Old Script Backup Before Run DDL Commands
I have a trigger that follows DDL commands in SQL Server and writes them to the table and now I need to write the script before the alter is made to the table. Is such a thing possible?
I can write the new script, that is, the modified version, to the table, but I cannot write the script before the update.

SQL Server doesn't have BEFORE triggers. DML triggers support FOR/AFTER and INSTEAD OF and Database/Server triggers only FOR/AFTER. This can be seen in the documentation.

I'd suggest you use something like SQL Audit instead, or use some kind of version control.

What's the difference of doing it before or after?
